# Is this patented in the UK?

Tags: patent-infringement

In reference to the patent: [WO2016179586A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2016179586A1)

Hi, ive discovered a manufacturer for this wallet, but also found a patent from a company called "the ridge" on the design, id like to know if this patent is valid in the UK, and if its possible to sell these in the UK

Answer (score 2):

Looking at it briefly, it is an application (patent pending) as opposed to a patent grant (enforceable.)

The application has the identifier PCT/US2016/031472 which indicates an international filing under the [Patent Cooperation Treaty](http://www.wipo.int/pct/en/faqs/faqs.html).

There is definitely a corresponding US filing, [US 14/706,019](https://www.google.com/patents/US20160324283) but you'd [have to search for a UK specific filing](https://www.gov.uk/search-for-patent).  (Patents must be filed for each territory. See Maca's note below on European/UK filing.)

The filing is relatively new so it may be a while before it is reviewed.  You should definitely research the UK patent database to make sure you're not violating (if granted) or opening yourself to future liability (patent pending) should the patent be granted.

Comment: Well answered. But it may be worth mentioning that a European patent application can apply to the UK too, but wouldn't necessarily show up at the UKIPO until after validation (which, to be fair, is automatic, but still takes time).

Comment: @Maca Appreciate the input.  I've added a note referencing your comment.